# Visual Studio not able to start

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013

My windows crashed and I had to reboot it. When I rebooted back into Windows I was not able to start my Visual Studio. I get following error:

[image]

And in my ActivityLog.xml I have the following:

```
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2015/05/13 14:43:49.628</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
    <hr>80131018</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I have tried removing .NET framework 4.5 and I have tried deleting the temp folders under my users local data.

I am running my Windows installation in Parallels on my Mac. This is my last resort before reinstalling my Windows. Can anyone point me in any directions?

EDIT:
I have tried repairing Visual Studio. Reinstalling Visual Studio. Repairing .NET framework. Nothing helped me.

Comment: Does this error happen when you open VS directly by itself (not by double clicking a VS-compatible solution, project, etc. file)?  Have you done disk and file-system checks to see if there's any corruption?  Have you tried running [`SFC /Scannow`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) to see if any system files have been corrupted?  Have you tried a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) back to a point before it crashed?

Comment: Good suggestions but unfortunately I was not able to restore the functionality. I think the only solution is for me to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing Visual Studio 2013 from Control Panel, Programs and Features.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, and anyway the OP says it didn't work.